# Updating a single attribute for a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, update-attributes

I have a user table, after the user is created I want to edit one attribute using the below code. This is my user edit view:

```
<h1>Please select below</h1>

<%= form_for @user do |f| %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :extra_activity %>
    <%= f.select(:extra_activity, [['P_Act', 1],['Ph_Act', 2], ['C_Act', 3]], class: 'form-control', required: true)  %></br>
  </div>

  <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg' %>
<% end %>
```

In my user controller I have the following methods for edit and update :

```
def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = User.all
    @user_id = params[:user_id]
end

def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
        redirect_to new_user_activity_path(@user)
    else
        redirect_to home_path 
    end
end
```

`user_params` are listed below:

```
  def user_params
     params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :surname, :previous_award, :chosen_award, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :extra_activity)
  end
```

When i initially create the user, `:extra_activity` is set to 0. When the user clicks submit on the edit form, nothing happens, the user is redirected to `home_path`. I just need to update the user's `:extra_activity` attribute to whatever they select in the form. Can anybody suggest where I am going wrong here? Not sure how to save the selected number, as the updated value for `:extra_activity`

UPDATE:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :activities, dependent: :destroy
   has_many :weeks, dependent: :destroy
   authenticates_with_sorcery!
   validates :password, length: { minimum: 3 }
   validates :password, confirmation: true
   validates :email, uniqueness: true, email_format: { message: 'has invalid format' }
end
```

Comment: can you post the params hash that is coming through?

Comment: im not sure what you mean by params hash - where could i find this?

Comment: in your update action do a: p params.inspect

get whatever is returned from the logs.

Comment: `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"hgnJEi/uzuckBeX6D6d0sJwPswRdcKxq9U5ieGr32eX8OLb40Q2ITg9U6H/uonC8YnbUpGb6Hjwbz1WdVgqgbQ==", "user"=>{"extra_activity"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Submit", "id"=>"1"}` Is this what you mean?

Comment: or maybe this? `{\"utf8\"=>\"✓\", \"_method\"=>\"patch\", \"authenticity_token\"=>\"+7hpWATV6j0pmqtYO3LDJd+eXpS2IEpUCSnp8e+h9cCBiRay+jaslALLpt3ad8cpIec5NI2q+ALnqN4U01yMSA==\", \"user\"=>{\"extra_activity\"=>\"1\"}, \"commit\"=>\"Submit\", \"controller\"=>\"users\", \"action\"=>\"update\", \"id\"=>\"1\"}`

Comment: I tried this and got it working just fine. I'm able to save the extra_activity value. Instead of @user.update_attributes(user_params), try @user.update(user_params).

Comment: @hade that still won't work for me, that's what I originally had and it doesn't update anything unfortunately

Comment: In your users table, how's the extra_activity column look like? Is it an INT value?

Comment: Look at the log file for any error messages when you click submit.

Comment: @hade yes `extra_activity` is an integer value in the table. @Prakash Murthy I'm not sure if this is an error, but it says rollback, so i think it is    `CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" = 'jgxy@hotmail.com' AND "users"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK`

Comment: if the user is not updated, there might be some validation which is failing. Have you tried to see what happens in the "else" case? Add

raise @user.errors.to_a.join(' - ')

to see what is going on.

Comment: Because it's going to the home_path, something goes wrong with the db validation. Put pp @user.errors just before the redirect_to home_path line.

Comment: Me and @pascalbetz, great minds think alike =D

Comment: i seem to get an error when i put `pp @user.errors` above my `redirect_to home_path`. i also can't see anything different happening when I add `@user.errors.to_a.join(' - ')` above the `redirect_to home_path` line. Sorry I'm just new to rails and confused

Comment: What @pascalbetz suggested was to add `raise @user.errors.to_a.join(' - ')` It should raise an error and you should be notified.

Comment: ok so the error that is thrown says the password is too short, it must be a minimum of 3 characters. Which doesn't make sense because the password I entered was 8 characters long. so i'm not sure what this means?

Comment: Can you please update the question with more information about validations in the User model. Now you are sending only `"user"=>{"extra_activity"=>"1"}` information and password validation is failing.

Comment: Maybe the user has been created to the database before the password validation has been added. And now when you are trying to update the user information with extra_activity -information it fails. Please check from the db that the password character length is actually over 3 chars.

Comment: @hade i updated the post with the validations - i'm using the sorcery gem which means i can't actually see the length of the password in the database. it saves a long encrypted version

Comment: @hade thanks for all the help. pascal's answer below worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading your comments and checking the update, i guess the solution is to add:

`validates :password, length: { minimum: 3 }, if: :password`

The password is most likely stored in hashed form and not in `password` column. So if you reload the user the attribute is not set.
The validation should be: IF the password is set, then make sure that it is at least of length 3 (which is pretty short).

You should make sure that the password that is stored is not changed when you update the user through this controller.